# Caret cursor color and size

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

How do I change the size and colour of the flashing cursor in my textfield using my storyboard for my Mac app.

I assume I have to connect it into the view controller script (control drag) and edit some uitextfield color parameter for the cursor?

But I don't seem to be getting anywhere fast. I am working in swift 2.2 with Mac app Storyboards. Like Ulysses and Taskpaper.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 3:**

Change YOURTEXTFIELD to your textfield and you are set:

```
(YOURTEXTFIELD.value(forKey: "textInputTraits") as AnyObject).setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "insertionPointColor")
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449309-insertionpointcolor

Comment: Well done, this is the correct answer! Should be on top.

Comment: Good, but partial: this does not answer how to change the size.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `_drawInsertionPointInRect` that's the private method that you need. Though you also need some other stuff I think... but it's all mixed into my code so I can't say for sure what it all is. Anyway search for `_drawInsertionPointInRect` and you'll get to some explanations.